# Does asking questions from a computer on same network counts the number of Question asked?

Tags: support, rate-limiting

I work in a small programming company of 5 people. Stack Overflow being a great help we use it, as it provides us solutions to our problems or at least provides the best suggestions to overcome difficulty.

The scenario is my colleagues have different Stack Overflow accounts but we share the same network, i.e our ISP is providing internet to our server computer and to that Server all our computers are connected.

What I want to know is:

I haven't posted any questions for several days, but my friends did. Today when I came to post a question there was this message:

> "You have reached your question limit."

Why is this happening? Does Stack Overflow store the IP address of our server due to which the question limit is reached as we all prefer Stack Overflow?

Comment: Yes, this is based on IP address to prevent easy bypassing by creating multiple accounts.